# Is it possible for a homotopy class and its inverse to be the same?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $x\in X$. We use $\pi_1(x)$ to denote the fundamental group at $x$ where the inverse of a homotopy class $[\alpha]$ is $[\alpha^{-1}]$. Just curious, is it possible that $[\alpha] = [\alpha^{-1}]$ for some $\alpha$ not homotopic to the identity loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Equivalently, is there a group $G$ with an element $g$ so that $g=g^{-1}$, this just means $g^2=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $\pi_1(X) = \mathbb Z / (2\mathbb Z)$, then if $\alpha$ is nontrivial, $\alpha^{-1}$ is also not null-homotopic, but there is only one non-trivial homotopy-class, hence $[\alpha] = [\alpha^{-1}]$.

For a concrete example of such a space take $X = \mathbb R \mathrm P ^2$.

In fact, you have such a class if and only if $\pi_1(X)$ contains elements of order 2, as $[\alpha^{-1}] = [\alpha]^{-1}$, hence your condition is equivalent to the statement that the group element $[\alpha] \in \pi_1(X)$ has order $2.$